# JMeter can't send CSV's data on localhost

Tags: jmeter, localhost

I need to send several files on my localhost by using the **CSV data set config** on JMeter.
Of course, this doesn't work and it seems the data aren't send.

In fact, **my CSV is read** : I got the paths in the request body when a file is sent, **but the data of this file aren't loaded** as you can see (this result is from à 8MB file) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG5li.png

My CSV data set config is good with a good configuration, so i don't understand why **only the path is sent**.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We need to see** how your [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) is configured in **order to be able to troubleshoot the issue**. It would also beneficial to ensure that CSV Data Set Config **really works** by checking the file path using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).

- If you need to **inline the file content into request body** you can use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

  [image]
- If you **need to send file(s) in form of [multipart-form/data](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)**

  - tick the relevant box
  - provide file(s) path(s) in the "Files Upload" tab

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

I need to **send files in form of multipart/form-data**.

I don't understand, I'm using a CSV data set config, and the paths of my files are good in the request body : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvNte.png

So why I have to upload my CSV file ?

[I'm using parameter instead of file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHflK.png) and my variables names are the same.